# How to lazy load request object when uploading 2G file with pyramid, WSGI and waitress

Tags: pyramid, waitress

I am using python pyramid and find out if one try to access self.request, the whole 2G file will be loaded to a temporary folder automatically. Instead, I would like to lazy load the file and pass the file pointer to another method where it can be uploaded to other server. Then I can save the time to load to disk twice.
Or Are there any recommended library(other than waitress) I can move to?

Comment: I removed some extenstive tags on the question, so that trigger happy StackExchange.com moderators are not unnecessarily closing this good question.

Comment: This should be a bugreport somewhere (either Pyramid or WebOb), not a question on SO.

Comment: Are there any other library (other than waitress) which I can move so as to avoid this problem?

Comment: In Pyramid self.request is actually a WebOb object. When you access the file from the POST it has to write it to disk because WSGI spec does not allow access to the POST body multiple times. Currently if the request body is made seekable (which happens when you access request.POST) the file is written to disk temporarily. So long as you don't use request.POST and thus make the body seekable you could use the raw WSGI input request.body_file_raw and write your own functions around it to not do multiple copies (but you will have to parse the input stream yourself).

Comment: @WichertAkkerman: This isn't a bug, Waitress has to write the file to disk when it receives the request, there is no way to keep it in memory. However an extra copy may be made by WebOb when accessing request.POST, that could be helped.

Comment: @ X-Istence: I would like to try self.request.body_file_raw and self.request.body_file_seekable. But Pyramid would just load the 2G file in with "self.request". Do you mean that I should use request_method='PUT' instead?

Comment: @JOE It's not Pyramid that loads the whole 2G file. Waitress has to save the entire request locally into a file, it can't save it in memory, and WSGI has no concept of streaming data in. From that it creates `wsgi.input`. Depending on the Pyramid/WebOb features that you use it will make the body seekable, and thus create another temporary file outside of the temporary file that waitress created. Then when it parses the body, it will create new temporary files for each of the uploaded files.